# How to install apps which are targeted for another country?

Tags: applications, google-play-store

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I circumvent regional restrictions in the Android Market?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/12538/how-can-i-circumvent-regional-restrictions-in-the-android-market)

I'd like to install an app from the Market which is limited to the USA (specifically [Google Music](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.google.android.music)). When I search for the app myself in the Market app on my phone, it does not find the app; it seems to be filtered.

So how do I install apps which are not meant for my country?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Before we got paid apps in the Android Market in Denmark, I used to use [Market Enabler](https://market.android.com/details?id=ch.racic.android.marketenabler) (requires root). This allowed me to pretend that I was a resident in another country, and thus buy paid apps from the Market.

Perhaps you can use the same solution, faking the market to believe you are from the US?

Comment: works like a charm!

Comment: Perfect, and good to know. :)

Comment: MarketEnabler no longer works. AndroidMarket checks for IP address as well to find the user's location. Can't cheat any more ;)

Comment: If that's the case then maybe you can connect via VPN or Proxy. Though I'm not sure as to how.