# Can not install in country

Tags: google-play-store

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to install apps which are targetted for another country?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/11154/how-to-install-apps-which-are-targetted-for-another-country)

i would like to loadthe bbc news app but i get the following error on android market place.

This app is incompatible with your Samsung GT-P7510.
Samsung GT-P7510
This item cannot be installed in your device's country.

any ideas on how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Try the [Market enabler app](http://www.appbrain.com/app/market-enabler/com.notenking.mf)