# How to get Google+ application even outside US?

Tags: google-play-store, google-plus

I have an account on Google+ but Android Market does not allow me to download Google+ application.

Comment: I live outside the US (UK) and I was able to download the application without issue from the Market

Comment: Since this isn't specifically an issue with Google+ but rather with country restrictions in the Market, this looks like a duplicate of http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/11154/how-to-install-apps-which-are-targetted-for-another-country

Comment: Have you tried on both the phone and the web?

Answer (score 6):

Well I couldn't download it from the market app on my phone in Germany, but I was able to install it from [Play Store](https://play.google.com/store).

Otherwise you might try installing **market enabler** and fake that you are in the US.

Comment: This is precisely the same Android Market that the asker says does not allow him to download the app. I also live out of the US and the market does not let me download it either.

Answer (score -1):

You can install from here but may be its in development phase and not activated

[Google+](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.plus&feature=search_result)

Comment: This is precisely the same Android Market that the asker says does not allow him to download the app.  I also live out of the US and the market does not let me download it either.

Comment: Why down vote? He is correct.

Comment: Thanks XperiaMiniPro... 
Seven vote for same my copied answer, but I got down vote Strange !

Answer (score -1):

If you don't mind getting it from untrusted sources, you can google "google plus android apk", and this will show you a list of repositories and forums to download it from.

Note that, as a is the nature of such, let's call them, untrusted sources, there's no guarantee that either they or the google query will persist for long, so I'm not even bothering to link to anybody.