# Accessing the Android Market using a US SIM card from outside US

Tags: google-play-store

I have a Nexus S phone with Android 2.3 and a SIM card from a Canadian carrier. While I'm in Canada, I want to download applications from Google's Android Market (e.g. Google Music) without rooting my phone.

Will it work to replace the SIM card with a US SIM card (e.g. AT&T GoPhone)?  If I did that, everything should work smoothly, correct?

Comment: You can install the Google Music .apk without rooting.

Comment: You'll be accessing the Market over Wi-Fi so I'm not sure this would help.  Is the phone unlocked?  (Related: [How can I circumvent regional restrictions in the Android Market?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/12538/how-can-i-circumvent-regional-restrictions-in-the-android-market))

Comment: @MatthewRead: yes, I am going to use a WiFi connection. I don't think ip address will be a problem, but if it is then I can use a WiFi that goes through a proxy. My phone is unlocked, I am not locked to any carrier (Nexus series are all unlocked).

Comment: @Flow: I am aware of that. I want to download these apps directly from the market (and be able to update them later directly from there). I don't like downloading the hassle and security risks of downloading the .apk files from other places (which are often outdated). If I can get this to work it would be much better.

Comment: I would appreciate if down-voter explains the reason for down-voting my question.

Comment: +1 I have no evidence, but I think that Google uses the carrier to determine the country of a particular user. The carrier also shows up on the market if you have signed in. But maybe they use additional more sophisticated methods.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried it but I think it should work just like the app [Market Enabler](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.notenking.mf&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImNvbS5ub3RlbmtpbmcubWYiXQ..) fakes the SIM ID.