# Is there any way to make Android Market "global"?

Tags: google-play-store

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I circumvent regional restrictions in the Android Market?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/12538/how-can-i-circumvent-regional-restrictions-in-the-android-market)

What I mean is, is there any way to make the recommendations offered by Android Market be the same as the ones shown on the Android Market website. The app version currently shows localised rankings, which is very annoying because there's a ton of low quality apps and regional stuff which I couldn't care less about.

Y'know, kinda like the option that you get on Youtube.

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to make the market global, but you can change your region with [`MarketEnabler`](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.notenking.mf&feature=search_result). Simply set it to US and you will see the same, as on the website.
*Notice: You need root access!*