# How to change my device's country?

Tags: google-play-store, settings, languages

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I circumvent regional restrictions in the Android Market?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/12538/how-can-i-circumvent-regional-restrictions-in-the-android-market)

Google just released Chrome for Android and I want to use it. But, for some (pretty irrational) reason, it is only available to certain countries. I therefore need to change mine. How do I do that?

Thanks

Comment: Sounds like you may want [How can I circumvent regional restrictions in the Android Market?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/12538/how-can-i-circumvent-regional-restrictions-in-the-android-market)

Comment: To change your Play Store country, you might want to refer to [this thread](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/42347/how-do-i-change-the-google-play-country) or [this page](http://techzog.com/mobile/google-play-store-country-change/) for the solution you are looking for.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Factory reset. However if you set up your phone to avoid roaming. Then it wouldn't matter. Had to ask this when I got my phone rushed it on the dealer and it was set on US even though I am in Canada, and I had to call customer service.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:
-Use an android cook rom (Cyanogen), try [Rom Manager](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.koushikdutta.rommanager) to simplify the process.

-Use [Market enabler](https://market.android.com/details?id=ch.racic.android.marketenabler) to fake some other providers (Verizon/ AT&T etc, but change to those two makes Google Market thinks your phone is in US).

Or you can try installing the beta version of Chrome that is already leaked on [xda](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?p=22279468)

Remember ICS only, lower version of Android OS will lead to apk parse error.