# Play store stuck in old country

Tags: google-play-store, localization

I moved from France to Italy, and it seems like my Play Store is stuck in France. The Operator is recognized correctly as Vodafone on the play store, but I still see the app recommendations in French and some Applications which should be available only in Italy are not downloadable (This item cannot be installed in your device's country)

How do I get play store to recognize that I have moved to a different country. My phone is a factory unlocked Galaxy SIII GT-I9300 with stock OS, purchased in France.

Comment: And I have already cleared the data and cache for Play store. didnt work.

Comment: Have a look at [How do I change the Google Play country?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/42347/how-do-i-change-the-google-play-country). It seem like Google Play uses also data from Google Wallet to determine your country.

Comment: @Flow: I am the author of the question you linked to and I can confirm that the procedure mentioned in the answer works. Can a mod please mark this question as a duplicate of that?