# How do I view a different country's Google Play store?

Tags: google-play-store

I would like to look at the Google Play store for a country different than my own, but I've spent an hour trying to figure out how to find or view the stores for any other country and I can't find the option to do so.

For iOS I just use iTunes and it has a country button at the bottom of the page where I can simply choose any country to view, I assumed for Google Play there has to be something similar and I'm just not able to find it.

EDIT: This answer for this isn't found in in this thread ([How do I change the Google Play country?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/42347/how-do-i-change-the-google-play-country)), the answer there was simply on how to view only one other country, and required that you make a purchase in that country. There must be another way.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I change the Google Play country?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/42347/how-do-i-change-the-google-play-country)

Comment: That question only covered purchases in other countries, and the answers required that you make a purchase in that other country. I need to see every country's app store, I can't reasonably make a purchase in every country to do that.

Answer (score 1):

One solution I've found was to use anonymous foreign proxies for each country I want to check. It's a pain finding a decent proxy for each separate country, but technically it works.