# Spotify in Croatia

Tags: google-play-store, spotify

I am from Croatia and I was able to install and use(run) Spotify *free* version(not Premiumm I didn't sign up for free Premium or anything). None of my friends can install (or run) it because in order to use Spotify in Croatia you would need to have either an Unlimited or Premium subscription. Now week after using it I get this error message after trying to log in: "You appear to be trying to log  into Spotify from a different country."
So obviously the first time I downloaded Spotify or Play Store thought I was in a different country. I was not using VPN or anything like that, so how can it be?
Other thing that interests me, can I trick Play Store or other app to think I'm in other country by changing my settings somehow?

P.S: I get promo messages form Spotify in Swedish language!

Comment: Could you clarify a little bit? By "installing", do you mean you can installed (but your friends couldn't) from Play Store, or all of you could install, but cannot run? ProGrammer's answer might give a clue, but it depends on this clarification. As for tricking Play Store, refer to [this question](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/42347/how-do-i-change-the-google-play-country/) (or it might be the case for you!)

Comment: I've edited! Tnx @AndrewT. I've answered my question with your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With help from [Andrew T.](https://android.stackexchange.com/users/44325/andrew-t) I've got the answer to my question. For the first time I've used my Google Wallet, so that must be the reason for changing the country settings also in Play Store under My apps I don't have visible Spotify although I've have installed it nor do I have it when I search apps Store.

Answer (score 1):

If I remember correctly, the first time you login with your new Spotify account, you can enjoy Premium for a month or so.
Your Premium trial period may have run out.
There could be country restrictions in place.
It has been a while since I last stumbled across this problem with a friend's computer.

Comment: The "Premium for a month" is plausible, but I'm not sure it is related to app installation in the first place (I believe it's controlled by Google, not Spotify). I have asked OP to clarify this a little bit further.

Comment: Tnx @ProGrammer for your help! I've up voted your answer although it's wasn't solution.

Answer (score 0):

MediaHint has a beta program you could join [MediaHint Beta signup](https://mediahint.com/support/device-beta) or you could try [Hola Free VPN](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.hola)