# Is Google Play Store geo-targeted?

Tags: google-play-store

Some companies are telling me that my games are better listed in some countries than in the US.

I'm using VPN to try to check if it's true, but the top free games seems to be the same in all countries. Am I wrong ?

Does the Google Play store have a different listing in different countries?

Comment: Well, yes listing order do varies from region to region like if you have uploaded the app from US then you ranking over the US is little more higher than over the other places it's called localisation (I guess) ! But the fact is yes your listing varies according to region.

Comment: As already answered, VPN doesn't work for Play Store. Or to put it simply, [you cannot cheat the country easily like previously](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/42347/how-do-i-change-the-google-play-country) (whether using Market Enabler app, or changing IP using VPN)

Answer (score 0):

Yes. For certain countries, Some Apps are geo-targeted. For example, Certain Video-Calling apps aren't available in the Middle-East.

Comment: I'm not talking about the availability of the app but the order listed. Ex: I get statistic from India site telling me that my app is #45 in their country, but in the US it's #123... So the listing order is not the same depending the countries. I want to know if it's true because my VPN connection doesn't change the order at all. App position are the same in every countries that I've looked.

Comment: @Warface: Are you using the Play Store app from VPN or the Play Store website? If I recall correctly, the Play Store app would use the device's home country when used overseas, I believe it records where you activated the phone, rather than figuring it or from your IP address.

Answer (score 0):

The Play Store uses the payment information you have on-file with them for geo-targeting. A VPN shouldn't make any difference in the results you see unless you change your payment info to match the country you want to test.