# Redeeming Google Play Gift Card to Change Country

Tags: google-play-store

I wanted to change the country of my Google Play from Philippines to US. Which you can find in a similar post [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/42347/how-do-i-change-the-google-play-country).

- I've tried changing my "Home address" in the settings section of my Google Wallet
- Tried removing my Google account on my smartphone and putting it back
- Uninstall updates and cleared the data of my smartphone's Google Play
- I also tried using VPN

And still, none of it works.

I can't fill the "Payment Method" because I don't have a US Visa or US Credit Card.

Will it work if I load a USD Google Gift Card? Will it change the apps to be displayed on my Google Play? I wanted to ask here first before I buy myself a USD Google Play Gift Card to make sure.

I wanted to do this because there are apps that I wanted to download which are only available in the US.

EDIT: I just loaded $10 (USD) to my Google Wallet account. Cleared the data of my Google Play. But the applications I wanted to download are still not available. Looks like the only solution is to fake your location and use a VPN (*which did not work for me, instead, my phone becomes vulnerable to a malware which drains the battery of my phone when it is on idle*).

Comment: A gift card should work.

Comment: @AaronGillion I just loaded $10 to my Google Wallet. But the apps I wanted are still not available.

Comment: What to do if Google says "Couldn't redeem this code. This code can only be used in LocationB", and I **am** currently in LocationB?