# How do i change play store region?

Tags: google-play-store, google

I have been dealing with this issue since i bought this phone ( Galaxy Note 4 ). I need to change my play store to the US, but I couldn't. I have tried many methods especially, changing my home adress of (google payment or wallet).
Many people used to download an app called (Hola and others) ,but i don't prefer to use apps in this way. In google play (Contact us) mentioned that I need to put a payment method related to US. Anyway, I don't have a payment for US.

Is there any way to do it?

Comment: What about using a VPN? Works fine for me.

Comment: You should read this also: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/42347/how-do-i-change-the-google-play-country

Answer (score 1):

You can update your home address whenever you want, including changing to a different country. If you're representing a company, enter your business address.

1. Sign into your Google Payments account at payments.google.com and click the Settings icon in the top corner. See screenshot: here [How to change Country or region on Google Play Store](http://www.gammerson.com/2016/12/change-country-region-google-play-store.html)
2. Click Edit next to the "Home Address" listed and update the address (please note this is different from the "Address Book" which holds shipping addresses).
3. Open the Play Store and navigate to any item available for download.
4. Click to begin a download until you reach the "Accept and buy" screen (no need to complete the purchase)
5. Close the Play Store, force stop and then clear data for the Google Play Store application (Settings > Apps > Google Play Store > Force Stop then Clear Data) or clear your browser cache
6. Re-open the Play Store. You should now see the Play Store that matches your default payment method’s billing country.

Note that if you don't immediately see the Play Store that matches your default payment method's billing country, it may take a few hours for this to take effect.

If you haven't yet added a payment method to your account for the first time, add a card directly from the Play Store with a billing address that matches your intended country location. Then, follow steps 3 through 6 to show your intended country's Play Store.

Some things to note...

For legal reasons, you'll need to sign new Terms of Service if you change your home country.
If your Google Play balance is higher than these amounts, you won't be able to change your home country. If it's under those amounts and you change to a country with a different currency, you won't be able to see or use your remaining balance until you switch back to a country where that currency is used.
If you have a Payments Balance higher than USD $10, or a Checkout Merchant account, you won't be able to change your country.

Comment: As said before: You must disclose your affiliation to the linked site. Please do so!