# Where to change country information at Samsung App Store?

Tags: settings, samsung-galaxy-tab

How can i change the country of Samsung App Store? i can't download any apps, because they said that "its not available for my country"?

Shows the following error

[image]

I have searched the internet for the solution, but didn't get the solution. For example#

- http://www.sammobile.com/forum/showthread.php?t=2938
- http://www.askmefast.com/How_can_i_change_the_country_of_my_samsung_galaxy_s3_i_cant_download_any_apps_because_they_said_that_its_not_available_for_my_country-qna3127637.html
- http://www.justanswer.com/android-devices/6um7b-change-country-location-samsung-s3.html

Please help me.

Comment: Though it might not directly solve your issue, you might also want to take a look at similar questions, e.g. [How to change country ?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/20857/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do as follows:

1. Go to *`Settings` → `Applications` → `Samsung Apps`* and then tap the `clear data` and `clear cache` buttons.
2. Back to all applications, find *Samsung Apps* and click on it. Select now the correct country.

**Note:** The correct country should be where you currently are, or the country in which you registered first. Try first country first, and if it is still does not work - simply repeat steps 1-2 above with the other country.

Hope it works for you!

Answer (score 1):

If your device is rooted then just install the Market Enabler app (you can search for the APK as you have to manually install it)

Once you run, grant it root access and then back up your current carrier details. Do a search for SIM operator codes. You should get a list of all carriers in all countries and their corresponding 5 digit numerical code. Enter and apply a code of your choice (I chose Vodafone UK).

Not sure if the next steps are necessary but I cleared the data on the Samsung Apps Store and My Gear Store.

When I loaded them back up again, all content was in English and prices were in pounds and pence. Donation version gives the option for the code to be set every time you reboot. (Disclaimer: I have no affiliation to the developer, I'm just grateful to finally have a solution to this ridiculous issue!)

Comment: Can you link to the app on a *legal* distribution site?

Answer (score 0):

Go to Application Manager under Settings and clear the app's stored info. Then, restart the app, and select the proper country.

Answer (score 0):

I got out of a Middle Eastern language and back to English by pressing: `Apps > Settings > Language and input > Samsung keyboard settings (and OK) > English UK`.

Comment: Welcome to the site. The OP is not trying to change language, he's trying to use the Samsung App Store. Does your answer have anything to do with that?

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the app store country, it's determined by the carrier you use. you can try searching the internet  for the app you want in apk. In china facebook is blocked and google play doesn't allow you to download it, but it's freely available elsewhere online in apk format.

Comment: Welcome to the Android Enthusiasts! Guess you've missed some points concerning this question. You still can can e.g. use a proxy abroad to make your device appear "elsewhere than you are". Apart from that, 2 different answers point out how to change the country within the app, one of them was accepted as solution. Did anything change? Does the solution no longer work? And who asked about "Google Play" here, and what has that to do with ***Samsung App Store***?

Answer (score 0):

Open samsung app, click samsung galaxy app link, read the URL at the end it should say "country code=  ", delete the country code you see, press enter, it will open a page saying select the country.
I hope it helps, let me know how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

I have the solution!

- Purchase a used SIM card from eBay from a carrier from a country where the Samsung app store is allowed.
- Insert the SIM and connect to WiFi and the Samsung app store would then work and you can download everything you want.
- When you're done remove the SIM and put back in your carrier's SIM card.

Answer (score 0):

The problem isn't that an individual app is in the wrong language, it's that the Galaxy App (Applications Manager) runs in the wrong language

Answer (score 0):

It is very simple. Create a new gmail id from the country where you are or change the country in the Gmail settings. I also faced the same problem but could install the app by changing the country.

Answer (score -1):

You can try un-installing the app (in Application Manager), it will ask if you want to replace the un-installed version with the "factory version". When that is complete you should be able to select the country of your choice.

n.b.

I also un-installed all updates on the app before I un-installed the app, I'm not sure if this helped with the outcome.

Comment: Which app are you talking about?