# Want to download an app from Kenya in the app store

Tags: google-play-store, localization

Possible duplicates of

[How can I circumvent regional restrictions in Google's Play Store?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/12538/how-can-i-circumvent-regional-restrictions-in-googles-play-store)

[How to change country?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/20857/how-to-change-country)

Nevertheless, as the answers provided in the previous threads were not satisfying for me, i wanted to ask again in case anyone had an updated answer. I want to download https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.internet&hl=en on my phone but it is not available in my country.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: do u even read my own title?:D

Comment: Perhaps you could explain **why** you find the answers in the linked questions insufficient. Did they not work for you? If so, what was the behavior you saw? Simply saying they were "not satisfying" is too vague.

Comment: market enabler is no longer being maintained

Answer (score 1):

yes correct , use this link for direct download from google play ,
http://apps.evozi.com/apk-downloader/

or chrome plugins :
http://apps.evozi.com/apk-downloader/#extension
or vpn or socks for change ip to usa or england.

Answer (score 0):

General practice for me, if I'm looking for an app that is either no longer available on Google Play, supposedly incompatible with my device (though I know it will work), or not available in my area; I go to Google, enter in the name of the app I'm looking for + "apk". So in your case that would be "Internet.org APK". Lots of times you'll find someone or some third party that has uploaded the apk file.

Another way is to use an APK downloader site like [APK Downloader](http://apps.evozi.com/apk-downloader/). Unfortunately this doesn't seem to work for the particular app you want.