# Changing Google Play from French to English

Tags: google-play-store, languages, localization

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I circumvent regional restrictions in the Android Market?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/12538/how-can-i-circumvent-regional-restrictions-in-the-android-market)

I recently bought a lovely Nexus 7 for my wife. We live in France although we are English. The Google Play store is French, but we want to buy English books, and download English films. How to we do this?

Comment: I've seen some reports that the Play Store follows the language of the device. Do you have `Settings > Language & input > Language` set to English (UK)?

Comment: @AlEverett: For apps, that's true. However, for books it isn't. I live in Korea but have my phone set to English. While I get English recommendations, everything else in the books section is in Korean.