# How do I access google play music from the Philippines?

Tags: google-play-music

I am not able to access the google play music because my country isn't supported. I used VPN with a US account and it asked me to login. When I used my email, I receive the error again that my country is unsupported. Is there any other option? You help is highly appreciated.

Comment: A quick google search gave me [this.](http://geniusgeeks.com/how-to-access-google-play-music-movies-books-magazines-outside-us/) Try this and see if it works.

Comment: See also: [How can I circumvent regional restrictions in the Android Market?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/12538/16575). @Papul you might want to make that an answer, including an excerpt of the description. Sounds promising.

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a gmail account using an US-based IP address. For that install any VPN app, run it, selecting the country as US, or any other country that supports Google Play Music. Then create a gmail account from the phone itself. Log into it, and you're done.

Answer (score 0):

It's because your e-mail was created using a Philippine IP address.

If you have a Android phone, root it. Note that this voids warranty, and may have a chance of bricking your phone.

Comment: Does rooting help? Will it let OP access Google Play from Philippines?

Comment: Rooting will not solve the OP's question at all, since Google's geolocation restriction are done via IP checking on their servers, not your device.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a VPN such as Hideninja [free](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cryptninja.vpn)/[paid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.hideninja.vpn) on Google Play. It will bypass geo restrictions.