# How can I install the UPS Mobile app in Sweden?

Tags: google-play-store

If I visit the American version of the Google Play Store while logged in I can search and find the app. But I am met with a message that says I can't install it.

> This app is incompatible with your [device name].

There's also an additional line if I click the little plus button which gives some sort of explanation.

> This item cannot be installed in your device's country.

I'm not really sure how to tell if I am on the American version of the Google Play Store. My Google interface language settings are set to English, and my Google searches usually return web pages in English. It seems as if you can't set the search result language to be anything else than English if you are using English as interface language with Google products. And besides, the "localized" Google Play Store for Sweden is in English too. So how do you tell them apart? It beats me!

[image: screen ups mobile]

I should mention that I was unable to find the app when I did a search for it on my Android device using the Play Store app. So does this mean it is restricted for users in Sweden? And if so, **how can I trick it to install anyway?** I tried finding the APK file for the app for manual installation but all the websites that host the file are bollocks! They require registration and some of them just point to the Play Store, and what not...

I use UPS on a daily basis. I am clueless as to why they would want to block their customers in Sweden from using their app. What do they have to gain with that?... this is no music or video service we're talking about, there should be no licensing bullshit involved here.

I did check the system requirements and my device should be supported. So I don't think that's it.

Is anyone else, outside the US, able to install this?...

Comment: Possibly relevant: [How can I circumvent regional restrictions in the Android Market?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/12538)

Comment: It's not giving me any problems installing it with a UK account, what display language is your phone set to?

Comment: Have they (Google) patched the VPN or MarketEnabler trick? I have stock ROM with root and s-off on a HTC Desire. I downloaded and manually installed the APK file of MarketEnabler from the pronject's Google Code page. Tried faking T-Mobile US and Verizon. It had no effect. So I registered with DroidVPN, installed the Tun.ko installer, which downloaded the proper Tun.ko module. I was then able to connect with DroidVPN to their US server FREE number 3. I then cleared data and cache for Play Store. I then tried faking it with MarketEnabler again. Didn't work!!

Comment: So any other bright ideas? Or an instruction on how to do this properly? Maybe I did something wrong?...

Comment: @GAThrawn Menu, Settings, Language & keyboard, Select language, is showing "English (Sweden)". So I guess it's set to Swedish locale but the display language is actually English. Maybe that's why the MarketEnabler trick didn't work? Now that I think of it I didn't actually reboot the phone. Do I need to do that? Here's another idea - could it be that I need a custom ROM installed on the phone, perhaps with some additional locale to choose from?...

Comment: I contacted UPS about this and they confirmed that the app is not available from Sweden yet. It is currently available in US, Canada, Germany, France, UK and Italy. They don't when it's coming to Sweden. It's stupid that they didn't make it available worldwide from the get go. I think I have done what I could to try to circumvent this restriction with no avail. I have given up. I won't waste any more time on this. Screw them! I'll just use Parcels. It's a great app, works every time and in any location!