# Get rid of google market localization limitation to install an app

Tags: google-play-store, localization, chromecast

I'd like to test last HBO GO android application to see how they implemented chromecast, but I'm in Canada and my devices are registered to play store Canada so I'm not able to install it. I have been looking for the single .apk on the web but I'm not sure if I could trust those I found. 
Does any body has an idea how I could get it or how to get rid of the localization limitations ?
Thanks

Comment: Have you seen our fine [google-play-store tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/google-play-store/info), especially with the link to [How can I circumvent regional restrictions in Google's Play Store?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/12538/16575)

Answer (score 2):

Try this - http://apps.evozi.com/apk-downloader/#guide

This site allows you to copy the url fromm the official app from Google Play and download it without a hassle. Enjoy.