# How do I download an app from another country?

Tags: google-play-store

I have a Samsung Galaxy S4 Mini and when I go to download certain apps and it will not let me because 'it is not available in my country', however other people within my country have these certain apps and I am confused.

Comment: I've just added the `google-play-store` tag to your question. [its tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/google-play-store/info) holds a pointer to the answer you're after: [How can I circumvent regional restrictions in Google's Play Store?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/12538/16575)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the Hola Android app yo spoof your location with the Google Play Store application. Never used it for this, but I imagine it should work fine.