# Google shows wrong country

Tags: google-play-store, google-account, google-wallet

Play Google does not show apps for my country. I visited another country and came back and store is stuck to that country, I tried clearing data, removing my addresses and cards from Google wallet (and adding them again), I have made purchases before and now when I try to purchase it show no availability for my country. Any help would be appreciated.

tinder gives next error: `labResult: Error checking for billing v3 support. (response: 3:Billing unavailable)`

**Edit:** there is restriction for every app which is paid or has in app purchases, country is Georgia

Comment: @bmdixon No, it's not, I have seen that thread and done suggested, but no help

Comment: Have you tried buying an app which has no country restrictions? Just chose any and buy it (and optionally return it within the 2h refund window). AFAIK that's the last trigger *Google Wallet* needs to update your location (accessing your credit card, or whatever). Shortly thereafter, it should find you again in the country you're in now.

Comment: @Izzy there are no apps that can be purchasable in my play store

Comment: That's pretty strange. Not all apps are "regionally restricted" – except for the point that some regions cannot buy any apps at all. Did that apply to "that country" (you see, it might help to explicitely name involved countries here)?

Comment: @Izzy yes there is restriction for every app which is paid or has in app purchases, country is Georgia

Comment: So that's a completely different case then: if playstore purchases are generally not available in your country, there's no "official way" you can go about that. In this case, what applies is rather [How can I circumvent regional restrictions in Google's Play Store?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/12538/16575)

Comment: Use the link that Izzy provided. By following one of the answers from that link and you should be up and running. I'm in the US, but I have used the first answer to allow me to download apps that aren't available in US.